# Java generics super syntax

Tags: java, generics

Why does the following work:

```
public void test(Class<? super Integer> c) { ... }
```

But the following doesn't:

```
public <T super Integer> void test(T c) { ... }
```

Is there any substantial difference I am missing? Using `extends` works just as expected.

Comment: public <T extends Integer> void test(T c) { ... } will work.

Comment: If you have `test(T)` where `T` is allowed to be superclass of `Integer`, then `test()` accepts *any object*. The generic parameter becomes pointless.

Comment: @khelwoodh why does the first version work though? Also, Integer extends Number and Object, but that doesn't mean any subclass of Object can be passed in - is that right?

Comment: @khelwood For example, the first version doesn't accept String.class

Comment: @Dimi `Object` is a superclass of `Integer`. So `T` is allowed to be `Object`. If you have a method `test(Object c)` then _any object_ can be passed to `test()`. Any instance of a subclass of `Object` is also an instance of `Object`.